Masked Image is not rendered in a JLayeredPane component
Here's how it works:
An image is imported with drag and drop. We apply a mask to it (re: maskPanel) and then when the mouse is released, a new BufferedImage is created from the original image and the mask (combined together) and rendered to imageLabel in the JLayeredPane. And then the maskPanel is cleared. What I don't understand is, as soon as I release the mouse, the mask disappears. My idea is, the newly masked image should have been rendered in the imageLabel by then. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:
package com.company.gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MaskWindow extends JFrame {
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private final int TARGET_WIDTH = 600;
    private final int STATUS_HEIGHT = 30;
    private BufferedImage originalImage;
    private ArrayList<Point> maskPoints;
    private static final int BRUSH_SIZE = 40;
    private static final Color MASK_COLOR = new Color(255, 0, 0, 10); // Semi-transparent red
    private MaskPanel maskPanel;
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    public MaskWindow() {
        setTitle("Image Mask Window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        imageLabel = new JLabel("Drop image here", JLabel.CENTER);
        imageLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_WIDTH));

        statusLabel = new JLabel("Ready for drop", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TARGET_WIDTH, STATUS_HEIGHT));
        statusLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        maskPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        maskPanel = new MaskPanel();
        maskPanel.setOpaque(false);

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_WIDTH));
        layeredPane.add(imageLabel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        layeredPane.add(maskPanel, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

        add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setupTransferHandler();
        setupMouseListeners();

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void setupMouseListeners() {
        maskPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (originalImage != null)
                {
                    maskPoints.clear();
                    maskPanel.clearMask();
                    addPoint(e.getPoint());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (originalImage != null) applyMask();
//                maskPanel.clearMask();
//                maskPoints.clear();
//                maskPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        maskPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                addPoint(e.getPoint());
                maskPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    private void addPoint(Point p) {
        double scaleX = (double) originalImage.getWidth() / maskPanel.getWidth();
        double scaleY = (double) originalImage.getHeight() / maskPanel.getHeight();
        Point scaledPoint = new Point((int)(p.x * scaleX), (int)(p.y * scaleY));

        if (!maskPoints.isEmpty()) {
            Point lastPoint = maskPoints.get(maskPoints.size() - 1);
            interpolatePoints(lastPoint, scaledPoint);
        }
        maskPoints.add(scaledPoint);
        maskPanel.addPoint(p);  // This calls the new addPoint method in MaskPanel
    }
    private void interpolatePoints(Point start, Point end) {
        int steps = 5; // Adjust this for smoother or rougher interpolation
        for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++) {
            int x = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * i / steps;
            int y = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * i / steps;
            Point interpolatedPoint = new Point(x, y);
            maskPoints.add(interpolatedPoint);

            // Scale back down for display
            double scaleX = (double) maskPanel.getWidth() / originalImage.getWidth();
            double scaleY = (double) maskPanel.getHeight() / originalImage.getHeight();
            Point displayPoint = new Point((int)(x * scaleX), (int)(y * scaleY));
            maskPanel.addPoint(displayPoint);
        }
    }
    private void applyMask() {
        if (originalImage == null) return;

        BufferedImage maskedImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = maskedImage.createGraphics();

        g2d.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.setColor(MASK_COLOR);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.1f));

        for (Point p : maskPoints) {
            int x = (int) (p.getX() * originalImage.getWidth() / imageLabel.getWidth());
            int y = (int) (p.getY() * originalImage.getHeight() / imageLabel.getHeight());
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - BRUSH_SIZE/2.0, y - BRUSH_SIZE/2.0, BRUSH_SIZE, BRUSH_SIZE));
        }

        g2d.dispose();
        displayMaskedImage(maskedImage);
    }
    private void displayImage(File file) throws IOException {
        originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        if (originalImage != null) {
            maskPoints.clear();
            maskPanel.clearMask();

            int originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
            int originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

            int newHeight = (int) ((double) TARGET_WIDTH / originalWidth * originalHeight);

            Image scaledImg = originalImage.getScaledInstance(TARGET_WIDTH, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
            imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
            imageLabel.setText("");

            imageLabel.setBounds(0, 0, TARGET_WIDTH, newHeight);
            maskPanel.setBounds(0, 0, TARGET_WIDTH, newHeight);
            layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TARGET_WIDTH, newHeight));

            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            statusLabel.setText("Image loaded: " + file.getName());
        }
    }
    private void displayMaskedImage(BufferedImage mImage) {
        if (mImage != null) {
            int newHeight = (int) ((double) TARGET_WIDTH / mImage.getWidth() * mImage.getHeight());
            Image scaledImg = mImage.getScaledInstance(TARGET_WIDTH, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
            imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
            imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TARGET_WIDTH, newHeight));
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    }
    private void setupTransferHandler() {
        layeredPane.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
                return support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
                if (!canImport(support)) {
                    return false;
                }

                Transferable transferable = support.getTransferable();
                try {
                    List<File> files = (List<File>) transferable.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                    for (File file : files) {
                        if (isImageFile(file)) {
                            displayImage(file);
                            statusLabel.setText("Image loaded: " + file.getName());
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    statusLabel.setText("Drop failed: Not a valid image file");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    statusLabel.setText("Drop failed: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private boolean isImageFile(File file) {
        String name = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        return name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg") || name.endsWith(".png") ||
                name.endsWith(".gif") || name.endsWith(".bmp") || name.endsWith(".webp");
    }

    private class MaskPanel extends JPanel {
        private BufferedImage maskImage;

        public MaskPanel() {
            maskImage = new BufferedImage(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }

        public void clearMask() {
            Graphics2D g2d = maskImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, maskImage.getWidth(), maskImage.getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void addPoint(Point p) {
            Graphics2D g2d = maskImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(MASK_COLOR);
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.1f));  // 10% opacity
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(p.x - BRUSH_SIZE/2.0, p.y - BRUSH_SIZE/2.0, BRUSH_SIZE, BRUSH_SIZE));
            g2d.dispose();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(maskImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MaskWindow().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

I tried SwingUtilities.invokelater on the mousePressed event. ChatGPT suggested Swingworker which didn't work. Even instead of getScaledInstance in applyMask(), I tried to drawImage() and clone a masked copy first. Nothing worked!

Your addPoint method scales the points to the originalImage domain already before adding them to maskPoints. So it’s not correct to do this transformation again in applyMask(). Besides that, your use of new BufferedImage(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_WIDTH, … in MaskPanel only works for square images or when the width is larger than the height. When the original image has a height larger that its width, the scaled image will have a height larger than TARGET_WIDTH, so the feedback while dragging will be cropped at the bottom.

It works for me.

@Holger, yep, I solved it like that. Thanks. You can write an answer so that I can select it as the best one.
